# Problem when downloading excel in php html

Tags: php, html

I have a problem downloading Excel on PHP.

Only the required data should be downloaded, but the results are all downloaded html themes.

[image: Excell Image]

```
header("content-type: application/vnd-ms-exel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Praktisi PAZ Indonesia.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:3%;background-color:silver;">No.</th>
      <th style="background-color:silver;">Nama</th>
      <th style="background-color:silver;">Email</th>
      <th style="background-color:silver;">Telepon</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $no=1;

    $H_P = $Mod_Tampil->tampil_all($db,"SELECT NAMA_PENGGUNA, EMAIL_PENGGUNA, TELEPON_PENGGUNA FROM PENGGUNA");

    if (!empty($H_P[1])) {
      foreach ($H_P[1] as $D_P) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:left;"><?= $no++."."; ?></td>
          <td><?= $D_P[0]; ?></td>
          <td><?= $D_P[1]; ?></td>
          <td><?= $D_P[2]; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php }
    } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For starters, remove the spaces in the attachment name.

Comment: This code snippet looks incomplete. There is a place where your template echoes a header. Remove this inclusion or hide the picture by a condition statement.